# NSDate get the value of the 30th day after today

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to set the value of a NSDate at the 30th day after today.
I search for a quick way to do that.

Tanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Apple docs for NSDate, there is a class method:

```
+ (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

60 seconds/minute * 60 minutes/hour * 24 hours/day * 30 days should give you the # of seconds needed.

So try:

```
NSDate *futureDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24 * 30];
```

Comment: One hopes you threw caution to the wind and discovered you could use a negative NSTimeInterval to get a date/time in the past.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it as follows:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

   // now a NSDate object for now + 30 days
   NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];


    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setDay:30];
    NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:now options:0];
    [offsetComponents release];

    [gregorian release];
```

Comment: This also works if you want to add simultaneously different components: you can add days, months, years, hours, minutes and seconds!